# Add image from URL in jPanel

Tags: java, image, url, jpanel, addition

I have a small problem, I have tried different solutions to add a image from URL in my jPanel, but I don't succeed. This is how my jPanel looks like:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Hello extends JPanel{

    JPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel();
    JPanel HomeWindowPanel;
    JLabel secondlbl = new JLabel("Hello");

    public Hello () {
        //I want to add a picture here from URL
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this sample code:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LabelDemoProject/src/components/LabelDemo.java

Specifically the createImageIcon method.